# How to add array items to <li> Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on something really simple, a short quiz, and I am trying to make the items I have listed in a 2-d array each display as a `<li>`.  I tried using the JS `array.join()` method but it didn't really do what I wanted.  I'd like to place them into a list, and then add a radio button for each one.

I have taken the tiny little leap to Jquery, so alot of this is my unfamiliarity with the "syntax".  I skimmed over something on their API, `$.each`...?  I'm sure this works like the for statement, I just can't get it to work without crashing everything I've got.

Here's the HTML pretty interesting stuff.

```
<div id="main_">
    <div class="facts_div">
        <ul>            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <form>
        <input id="x" type="button" class="myBtn" value="Press Me">
    </form>
</div>
```

And, here is some extremely complex code.  Hold on to your hats...

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    var array = [["Fee","Fi","Fo"], 
    ["La","Dee","Da"]];
    var q = ["<li>Fee-ing?","La-ing?</li>"];


    var counter = 0;

    $('.myBtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#main_ .facts_div').text(q[counter]);
        $('.facts_div ul').append('<input type= "radio">' 
            + array[counter]);
        counter++;

        if (counter > q.length) {
            $('#main_ .facts_div').text('You are done with the quiz.');
            $('.myBtn').hide();
        }

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<div id="main_">
    <div class="facts_div"> <span class="question"></span>

        <ul></ul>
    </div>
    <form>
        <input id="x" type="button" class="myBtn" value="Press Me" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //

    var array = [
        ["Fee", "Fi", "Fo"],
        ["La", "Dee", "Da"]
    ];
    var q = ["Fee-ing?", "La-ing?"];


    var counter = 0;

    //cache all the possible values since they are requested multiple times
    var $facts = $('#main_ .facts_div'),
        $question = $facts.find('.question'),
        $ul = $facts.find('ul'),
        $btn = $('.myBtn');

    $btn.on('click', function () {
        //display the question details only of it is available
        if (counter < q.length) {
            $question.text(q[counter]);

            //create a single string containing all the anwers for the given question - look at the documentation for jQuery.map for details 
            var ansstring = $.map(array[counter], function (value) {
                return '<li><input type="radio" name="ans"/>' + value + '</li>'
            }).join('');
            $ul.html(ansstring);

            counter++;
        } else {
            $facts.text('You are done with the quiz.');
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
    //
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TN34k/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each` to iterate over `array[counter]` and create `li` elements for your options:

```
var list = $('.facts_div ul');
$.each(array[counter], function() {
    $('<li></li>').html('<input type="radio" /> ' + this).appendTo(list);
}
```

The first parameter is your array and the second one is an anonymous function to do your action, in which `this` will hold the current element value.

Also, if you do this:

```
$('#main_ .facts_div').text(q[counter]);
```

You will be replacing the contents of your element with `q[counter]`, losing your `ul` tag inside it. In this case, you could use the `prepend` method instead of `text` to add this text to the start of your tag, or create a new element just for holding this piece of text.

Comment: I wish I didn't have to pick only one best answer man.  You guys both helped me a lot.  But, his code helped me realize that I needed to cache items and it had a little more information in it.  I'll definitely try and use `$.each` though.